# Ubuntu Studio 20.10 can't change workspace with keyboard shortcut

Tags: workspaces, 20.10

What the title says, I have eight workspaces separated in two rows with four columns each. I can change by clicking with the mouse, but the Ctl+Alt+Left/Right arrow keys doesn't work.
Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Solution:
Had to go to System Settings -> Shortcuts -> Global Shortcuts -> KWin. There I located the "Switch to Desktop x" actions (defaults were Ctl+F1 for Desktop 1, etc.).

Comment: Could you add your solution as a separate answer? After this, you can wait some days and set it as "accepted"

Comment: @LorenzKeel done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now solved it. Had to go to System Settings -> Shortcuts -> Global Shortcuts -> KWin. There I located the "Switch to Desktop x" actions (defaults were Ctl+F1 for Desktop 1, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

From https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-workspaces-switch.html.en

> **Switch between workspaces**
>
> *Using the mouse*:
>
> 1. Open the Activities overview.
> 2. Click on a workspace in the workspace selector on the right side of
>    the screen to view the open windows on that workspace.
> 3. Click on any window thumbnail to activate the workspace.
>
> *Using the keyboard*:
>
> - Press Super+Page Up or Ctrl+Alt+Up to move to the workspace shown
>   above the current workspace in the workspace selector.
> - Press Super+Page Down or Ctrl+Alt+Down to move to the workspace
>   shown below the current workspace in the workspace selector.

If you have other sources where you got the shortcuts, you may post it as a reference.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of that, but it doesn't work. Super+arrow affects the window in the foreground - e.g. with the web browser in focus, Super+up shrinks the window on the half top part of the screen). While I was on 20.04, the Ctl+Alt+Left/Right/Up/Down combination was working fine. Since I upgraded to 20.10 it doesn't work.